# Center title and buttons in a dialog

Tags: css, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/kKT2V/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#te').dialog({
        title: 'saved',
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        width: 500,

        buttons: [{
            text: "Unpause",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }

        }]


    });

    clearInterval(interval);

});
```

This alert has a title and a button. Is there a way to change their position? I want to center them, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kKT2V/2

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar, .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    text-align: center;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Your browser's document inspector is your friend.

Comment: Ah it was from CSS, thought it can be done through a special JQUI thing. I'm still a bit confused about the inspector since it has lots of things.